# Django 2 static files

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I know this has been asked about a million times, but just don't get Django's static file handling. In prod I will deploy in s3 which already works nicely. But in dev (local running) not so much.

Problem 1:
If I set the config to this:

```
if ENVIRONMENT == "dev":
  BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  STATICFILES_DIRS = [
      os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
  ]
```

I can not run collectstatic as of the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

OK, makes sense, so I configure it to the following Problem 2:

```
if ENVIRONMENT == "dev":
  BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Now I can run collectstatic. But if run the server it will not find the static files:

> "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404

What I don't get: The Problem 1 can server the static files, which Problem 2 collects...
How do I configure Django 2 to simply collect and server static files within one simple 'static' folder within the root of my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is puzzling. You clearly need to define *both* `STATIC_ROOT` *and* `STATICFILES_DIRS`; the second is where the files are collected from, and the first is where they're collected to - and served from.

In any case, in dev you don't need to run collectstatic, so I'm not sure why you're asking this.

Comment: oh well that's it. I do not need to run collectstatic in dev... thank you! That was it were I got confused.